# rake aborted! TypeError: Parts is not a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, typeerror, abort

Well I got another error now with my database this time saying one of the classes I made "Parts" is not a class. I can't seem to know where this is tracing from

[image: rake Parts type error]

and here is my Parts database values (the file name is parts.rb)

```
class Parts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :parts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :category_id
    end
  end
end
```

my parts controller:

```
class PartsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize, :except => :index

  def index
    @parts = Part.all
  end

  def new
    @part = Part.new
  end

  def show
    @part = Part.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @part = Part.new(part_params)
      if @part.save
        redirect_to part_path(@part)
  end
end

  def edit
    @part = Part.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @part = Part.find(params[:id])
      if @part.update_attributes(part_params)
        redirect_to @part
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @part = Part.find(params[:id])
      @part.destroy
        redirect_to parts_path
    end

  private
  def part_params
    params.require(:part).permit(:description, :name)
  end

end
```

my parts model is just

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you generate the migration file with model by command like

```
bundle exec rails g model Part name:string description:text category_id:integer
```

it will create the migration file `2016...09_create_parts.rb`

and it will be look like

```
def CreateParts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :parts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :category_id
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It may just not like 'Parts' as a class name conflicting with something in the model or controller. or you have a `Parts` module defined somewhere?

I suggest changing the migration class name to, say, `CreateParts`, ie.

```
def CreateParts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     …
  end
end
```

And I'd change the filename too just in case (2016…09_create_parts.rb)

Comment: Thanks this helped out a lot! I did my migrations wrong and had to change the class name and the filename